# In the $\Lambda$CDM model, is the cosmological constant always interpreted as the vacuum energy contribution?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

As in the title, in the [$\Lambda$CDM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model), is the cosmological constant always interpreted as the vacuum energy contribution? Or is the origin left open?
If I say  that "it is usually interpreted as the vacuum energy  but its origin can also be a barotropic fluid with constant dark energy equation of state parameter"  am I still within the $\Lambda$CDM model?

Comment: I believe that this is a "distinction without a difference". What experiment can tell?

Comment: @JohnDoty ok but what's the official explanation for the cosmological constant in the LCDM model? is it the vacuum energy or it is just one possibility? Is it possibile that there is no cosmological constant and simply we have not detected yet the dark energy particle?

Comment: It's a model. It captures the acceleration we see. Nature doesn't give us explanations: nature gives us phenomena.